# Python - Selenium find_element_by_xpath("") displays "expected string or bytes-like object"

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Application versioning: 
Python: v3.5.4

Hello and good day!

I'm trying to scrape Facebook posts and fetch the **number of comments** a post has with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# Omitted some codes here
# To summarize, the codes above let me log in to my dummy account in Facebook
# Codes above tested if there's an existing cookie, or a new log-in instance, then refresh to FB

fb = webdriver.Firefox() 
fb.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
fb.get(url)

comments = fb.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="fbFeedStoryUFI/feedbackSummary"]')
print(comments)
```

But when I run my python script it is telling me this:

```
expected string or bytes-like object
```

Formerly, I was able to scrape the number of reactions a post has with this code:

```
reactions = fb.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-testid="UFI2ReactionsCount/sentenceWithSocialContext"]').click()
modal = fb.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@defaultactivetabkey="all"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
soup = BeautifulSoup(modal, 'html.parser')
```

And there were no errors, am I doing something wrong here? I would like to thank you in advance for those who can help me :)

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: hello sir @Guy it's on the line where i print the **comments** variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
comments = fb.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="fbFeedStoryUFI/feedbackSummary"]')
```

this line, return whole list of objects, and in next line you are trying to print it while python expects string or byte. What I would have done:

```
comments = []
number_of_comments = len(fb.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="fbFeedStoryUFI/feedbackSummary"]'))
for x in range(1, number_of_comments):  # indexes of div/li and other markers starts at 1
   comment = fb.find_element_by_xpath(f'//div[@data-testid="fbFeedStoryUFI/feedbackSummary"]/li{x}') # something like that, you need to check xpath
   comments.append(comment)
```

Comment: it's displaying `line 129
    comment = fb.find_element_by_xpath(f'//div[@data-testid="fbFeedStoryUFI/feedbackSummary"]/li{x}') # something like that, you need to check xpath
                                                                                                   ^`

error around the **{x}**

Comment: @JueViole17 I think you have to separate the variable eg '//div[@data-testid="fbFeedStoryUFI/feedbackSummary"]/li{'+x+'}'

Comment: @JueViole17 When using a variable in a string statement, you should parse it. End the string, add the casted version of the variable to the string and then add the rest of the string.

Comment: Although Python will tolerate non casted variables with different types being added, it can be the cause for some buggs later on.

Comment: if you are adding f before 'some text {f}' then it will work fine, here's sample of webscrapper that work perfectly in my current project:
`job_title_xpath = f'{xpath_base}[{i}]/offer-item/a/div[2]/div[1]/span'`

Comment: @JueViole17 Yeeees, it will return error becuase as I said in `# something like that, you need to check xpath` you will need to check xpath for element you want. I don't know what is xpath to every element in all elements returned by `find_elements_by_xpath`

Answer (score 0):

To get `number of comments` you can use:

`.find_elements_by_css_selector('._3hg-._42ft')`, and use iteration to extract the text.

But it will return some top post, because the posted below will appear if you scroll first.

```
comments = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('._3hg-._42ft')

for number in comments:
    print(number.text)
```